# Shell script Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")

Tags: shell

I'm writing a shell script to start a `Zookeeper` server and write logs in `zookeeper.out` `nohup` file, but when I try to start it, the following error appears:

```
> : not foundh: 2: zookeeper.sh:
: not foundh: 8: zookeeper.sh:
: not foundh: 10: zookeeper.sh:
---- Starting Zookeeper ----
: not foundh: 12: zookeeper.sh:
: not foundh: 13: zookeeper.sh: }
: not foundh: 14: zookeeper.sh:
---- Stopping Zookeeper ----
: not foundh: 17: zookeeper.sh:
: not foundh: 18: zookeeper.sh: }
: not foundh: 19: zookeeper.sh:
: not foundh: 21: zookeeper.sh: stop
: not foundh: 22: zookeeper.sh: start
: not foundh: 23: zookeeper.sh: }
: not foundh: 24: zookeeper.sh:
zookeeper.sh: 25: zookeeper.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

    JAVA_HOME=""
    KAFKA_HOME="/home/ubuntu/maxFlow/kafka_2.12-1.1.0"
    APP_HOME="/home/ubuntu/maxFlow/"
    APP_NAME=max-flow-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    APP_PORT=80

    start() {

        echo "---- Starting Zookeeper ----"
nohup $KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 & > zookeeper.out
    }

    stop() {
         echo "---- Stopping Zookeeper ----"
         nohup $KAFKA_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1 & > zookeeper.out
    }

    restart() {
             stop
             start
    }

    case "$1" in
      start)
            start
            ;;
      stop)
            stop
            ;;
      restart)
            stop
            start
            ;;
      *)
            echo "No case"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    exit 0;
```

I took the syntax for the script from `https://www.shellscript.sh/case.html`. Thank you

Comment: Can you post the other script?
And I don't understand "> /dev/null 2>&1 & > zookeeper.out", you output standard output to /dev/null, then error output to standard output ... so the output to zookeeper.out makes no sense here.

Comment: this is the only script, and it is not working for some reason

Comment: i removed the `>zookeeper.out` and it is still not working

Comment: I copied your whole script and executed it - without problems. On what system and how are you starting the script?

Comment: I answered my own question. Thank you :).

Comment: Ok, nice. Don't hesitate to upvote comments you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a virtual machine and I started the editor with windows notepad and it converted the script to `dos`. So, I ended up installing `dos2unix`, which I used to convert the script. Then, the script worked.